recorrer múltiples arreglos
estoy haciendo un sistema de loterías,en el apartado de ventas,para un tipo de sorteo en el cual se debe registrar un número y dos montos,además se tiene la posibilidad de agregar más grupos,es decir,campos para otro grupo de un número y dos montos,lo que quiero es recorrer esos arreglos y guardarlos en una tabla con campos para el número y el monto,en cuanto al monto quiero generar una cadena con los dos montos asociados con cada número y así guardarlos en el campo correspondiente,el código que tengo ahorita es el siguiente:
    $numeroarr = "";

  $numeroarr = !empty($_REQUEST['numero']) ? $_REQUEST['numero'] : null; 

#var_dump($numeroarr);
$montoarr = "";

  $montoarr = !empty($_REQUEST['monto']) ? $_REQUEST['monto'] : null;

$monto_final = array();

  if(!empty($montoarr)){
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($montoarr); $i++) {
            if(!empty($montoarr[$i])){
                $monto = $montoarr[$i];
                $numero = $numeroarr[$i];
                
  $sql = "INSERT INTO ventas(id_listero,id_puesto,tipo_sorteo,fecha,numero,monto) VALUES (:id_listero,:id_puesto,:tipo_sorteo,:hoy,:numero,:monto)";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id_listero', $id_listero, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':id_puesto', $id_puesto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':tipo_sorteo', $tipo_sorteo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->bindParam(':hoy', $hoy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':numero', $numero, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':monto', $monto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();
 
 }
 }
 }

El error que me tira es Warning:  Undefined array key 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\loteria\guardar-venta.php on line 102
Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'numero' cannot be null, agradezco cualquier ayuda.

$numeroarr = "";

  $numeroarr = isset($_REQUEST['numero']) && is_array($_REQUEST['numero']) ? $_REQUEST['numero'] : [];
$montoarr = isset($_REQUEST['monto']) && is_array($_REQUEST['monto']) ? $_REQUEST['monto'] : [];



$monto_final = [];
 if(!empty($montoarr)){
  
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($montoarr); $i++) {
            if(!empty($montoarr[$i])){
                $monto = $montoarr[$i];
                
                array_push($monto_final,$monto);
                
                
                $numero = $numeroarr[$i];
                $monto_final = implode(",", $monto_final);
                
  $sql = "INSERT INTO ventas(id_listero,id_puesto,tipo_sorteo,fecha,numero,monto) VALUES (:id_listero,:id_puesto,:tipo_sorteo,:hoy,:numero,:monto_final)";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id_listero', $id_listero, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':id_puesto', $id_puesto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':tipo_sorteo', $tipo_sorteo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->bindParam(':hoy', $hoy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':numero', $numero, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':monto_final', $monto_final, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();
 $monto_final = [];
 }
 }
 }

He cambiado la forma de enviar las variables,lo envío como una cadena json y luego lo convierto en arreglo con json_decode,lo recorro con foreach,si embargo,solo me almacena el primer valor del monto,este es el código:
$cadena = "";

$montos = "";
if(isset($_POST['cadena'])) 
{
  $montos = $_POST['cadena']; 
}



$cadena = json_decode($montos);


foreach ($cadena as $sorteo) 
{
   echo $sorteo->numero."<br>";
  echo $sorteo->monto."<br>";
  $numero = $sorteo->numero;
  $monto = $sorteo->monto;
  $sql = "INSERT INTO ventas(id_listero,id_puesto,tipo_sorteo,fecha,numero,monto) VALUES (:id_listero,:id_puesto,:tipo_sorteo,:hoy,:numero,:monto)";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id_listero', $id_listero, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':id_puesto', $id_puesto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':tipo_sorteo', $tipo_sorteo, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->bindParam(':hoy', $hoy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':numero', $numero, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':monto', $monto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();
}




¿Por que al asignar las variables, una de las posibilidades es que queden NULL? eso afectaría al for directamente. Que tipo de variables son las obtenidas por request y por que no las validas ?

@Excorpion Eso es para validar si el arreglo está vacío,es lo mismo que esto: if(isset($_REQUEST['numero']) AND !empty($_REQUEST['numero']))
{
$numeroarr = $_REQUEST['numero'];
} .Las variables son todas números

No estás validando si el arreglo está vacío, estás diciendo que el arreglo es NULL, cosa que no es lo mismo que un arreglo vacío.

@Excorpion Se asigna null en caso que esté vacío,que en realidad nunca lo estará,porque del lado del cliente puse una restricción para que se envíen al menos un grupo de un número y dos montos.

De nuevo, null y vacío, son cosas diferentes. Tu quieres asignarlo vacío, entonces asignalo vacío, no null.

En la asignación de las variables, estás erroneamente asignando NULL a las variables.
$numeroarr = !empty($_REQUEST['numero']) ? $_REQUEST['numero'] : null; 
$montoarr = !empty($_REQUEST['monto']) ? $_REQUEST['monto'] : null;

Durante el error, esto es mencionado también:

Column 'numero' cannot be null --inglés 
Columna 'numero' no puede ser null --español

Luego, haces una validación, y solo compruebas si el arreglo esta EMPTY. 
NULL y EMPTY son cosas diferentes, empty es vacío, en este caso un arreglo vacío, y NULL, es una variable sin asignar, es decir, que no es ningún tipo de variable, tampoco es un arreglo.
Entonces, vamos a corregir esta asignación a lo siguiente:
$numeroarr = isset($_REQUEST['numero']) && is_array($_REQUEST['numero']) ? $_REQUEST['numero'] : [];
$montoarr = isset($_REQUEST['monto']) && is_array($_REQUEST['monto']) ? $_REQUEST['monto'] : [];

Ahora, directamente a la variable que estamos asignando, le hacemos las comprobaciones:

isset(variable): comprobamos que la variable existe o no.
is_array(variable): comprobamos que la variable sea un arreglo o no. (OJO si la variable no es un arreglo, no es necesaria esta)
Si las condiciones se cumplen, asignamos el valor correctamente, de modo que sabremos que es un arreglo y tiene cargado el valor correctamente.
Si no se cumplen las condiciones, la variable será un arreglo vacío.

Si la variable llega a ser un arreglo vacío, esta quedara como:
$variable = [];
var_dump($variable); //Esto mostrará array(0){}

Anteriormente, al asignar un null, tu variable quedaba de la siguiente forma:
$variable = null;
var_dump($variable); //Esto mostrará NULL

Entonces, cuando más tarde haces la comprobación empty, se evalúará correctamente. (agregué el else, por que tampoco tienes uno)
if (!empty($montoarr)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($montoarr); $i++) {
        if (!empty($montoarr[$i])) {
            $monto = $montoarr[$i];
            $numero = $numeroarr[$i];
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "La variable montoarr está vacía";
}


A través de la discusión por chat con el usuario, se llegó a la siguiente corrección final:
// Validamos que la cadena sea válida
if (is_array($cadena)) {
    foreach ($cadena as $sorteo) {
        // Verificamos que cada objeto $sorteo contenga las propiedades 'numero' y 'monto'
        if (isset($sorteo->numero, $sorteo->monto)) {
            echo $sorteo->numero . "<br>";
            echo $sorteo->monto . "<br>";
            $numero = $sorteo->numero;
            $monto = $sorteo->monto;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO ventas(id_listero, id_puesto, tipo_sorteo, fecha, numero, monto)
                    VALUES (:id_listero, :id_puesto, :tipo_sorteo, :hoy, :numero, :monto)";
            
            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id_listero', $id_listero, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id_puesto', $id_puesto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':tipo_sorteo', $tipo_sorteo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':hoy', $hoy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':numero', $numero, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(':monto', $monto, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            //Agregamos un try catch para los errores de la consulta
            try {
                $stmt->execute();
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error en la inserción: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            echo "Error: El objeto sorteo no tiene 'numero' o 'monto' definidos.<br>";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: JSON inválido o vacío.";
}


Gracias,ahora,cómo puedo resolver el problema de "Undefined array key 2" ?

Muestra todo el error, la descripcion completa, e indicame la línea del error, ya que el error mismo lo puede mencionar.


Warning:  Undefined array key 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\loteria\guardar-venta.php on line 107
Este sería en esta línea : $numero = $numeroarr[$i];


Según eso, estás intentando acceder a la posición [1] de $numeroarr durante el for. Es decir, que no hay posición 1, ese arreglo está vacío, o no es un arreglo. No se como es el código actual en su totalidad.

for ($i = 0; $i < count($montoarr); $i++) {
if(!empty($montoarr[$i])){
$monto = $montoarr[$i];
            array_push($monto_final,$monto);
            $numero = $numeroarr[$i];
            $monto_final = implode(",", $monto_final);  aquí hago un insert  } } }


No, mira, al final de la publicación, sin editar el primero código, añade, después de la imagen TODO el código actualizado e identado. Pegalo, seleccionalo, y dale al botón { } que está en el editor de texto, así saldrá bien visto, y no como se vee en el comentario. Yo sabré cuando hayas editado la publicación.

Antes del IF, solo estás comprobando una variable, no ambas.

Me permito recomendar: 1. NO se debería usar $_REQUEST, sino la super global específica del método que envía esos datos, que suele ser o $_GET o $_POST Se reduce así un posible vector de ataques (ver respuestas). 2. Para recuperar los datos, usar fusión de null en vez de ternarios. Dan más claridad y simplicidad al código. Por ejemplo: $numeroarr=$_POST['numero'] ?? NULL; Y luego para verificar: if ($numeroarr) { // } else { // }

Para la primera, vamos a consultar al OP si está usando GET o POST y añadiré el cambio a la respuesta. La segunda, es cierto, se vee mucho más simple de ese modo, me gusta. Y para verificar, si, estoy esperando la verificación correcta del código.

@Excorpion no entiendo lo de que solo estoy comprobando una variable antes del if y las variables las estoy enviando por POST

Perfecto, entonces los REQUEST deben ser cambiados por POST para obtener la información, como lo indica Cedano. Y fijate que dentro del for, obtienes la data de los arreglos, pero recorres ambos arreglos, con el largo de montoarr, si numeroarr es más corto que ese, tendrás un indice fuera del arreglo, entonces hay que comprobar los arreglos por separado, o, los arreglos deben tener el mismo largo.

@Excorpion los arreglos siempre serán de largo diferente,en este caso siempre es un número que está asociado con dos montos,mi idea es generar una cadena separada por comas con los dos montos y guardarlo en un solo registro con ese número y en otro campo pues esa cadena con los dos montos

Continuemos el debate en el chat...
